Cluster decomposition property of Wightman functions made up from Wick monomials
For brevity, I will focus only on Wightman functions for a single scalar field.
Among the Wightman axioms is the property called "cluster decomposition". It states that for any space-like $4$-vector $a$, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} W(x_1, \cdots, x_j, x_{j+1} +\lambda a, \cdots, x_n+\lambda a)=W(x_1, \cdots,x_j)W(x_{j+1}, \cdots, x_n)
\end{equation}
where $\bigl\{ W(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \bigr\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of tempered distributions (=Wightman functions).
Theorem 3.7 in PCT, Spin, Statistics and All That states this as a requirement for the reconstruction theorem and Osterwalder-Schrader axioms describe its Euclidean version too.
However, it is not clear to me whether Wick products of free scalar fields satisfy this clustering property or not.
The paper by Fredenhagen, Brunetti and Kohler gives a rigorous construction of Wick products on a general hyperbolic manifold. Here, Theorem 5.7 states that the Wick monomials are well-defined Wightman fields, from which I understand that their VEVs are Wightman functions as in Theorem 3.7 of PCT, Spin, Statistics and All That.
However, I cannot find any mention of clustering in the paper. In fact, verification of clustering for Wick products requires interchange of two limits, which does not seem easy to justify. So, I would like to ask for any explanation.

Oops..I have not read the PCT book carefully enough..
Theorem 3.4 in the PCT book actually "derives" the clustering of Wightman functions from the Wightman fields.
As Theorem 5.7 in the Fredenahgen paper proves that Wick monomials are Wightman fields, their VEVs are indeed Wightman distributions satisfying all properties in Theorem 3.7 in the PCT book.
It seems that such background knowledge is assumed in the Fredenhagen paper, and it does not bother to discuss all the details.
Please correct me if I am mistaken again.

Brunetti, Fredenhagen and Köhler actually only prove the Wightman axioms that make sense in any globally hyperbolic space-time - namely, positivity and microcausality (a.k.a. locality). Temperedness and Poincaré invariance usually go out the window but are pretty immediate to prove in Minkowski space-time from e.g. formula (21), pp. 650 of BFK (i.e. they follow from the corresponding properties for the Klein-Gordon 2-point function).

The spectral condition only survives in general space-times as its (micro)local remnant, i.e. the microlocal spectrum condition, and that's the remaining property that BFK prove. However, it's not difficult to get the spectral condition in Minkowski space-time because the Wick monomials act on the same Hilbert space as the original (Klein-Gordon) field and are acted upon the unitaries implementing the Poincaré group in the same way, so the joint energy-momentum spectrum must also be the same. Poincaré invariance also follows (even more easily) from these facts, of course.

In due time: I don't quite get your quotes on "derives" in your second sentence. Did you mean to merely emphasize / italicize that term, or are you somehow questioning the rigor of Streater-Wightman's proof of the cluster decomposition property?

@PedroLauridsenRibeiro The PCT book literally "verifies" in Theorem 3.4 clustering based on the four axioms presented in the start of Chapter 3. They say that an argument by Ruelle is used in the proof. That is what I meant. I believe that everything is done with full rigor. I can change the wording if it confuses you.

@PedroLauridsenRibeiro And yes, I was sloppy about temperedness and Poincare covariance. Thank you for pointing that out.

That's fine about the quotes, I just wanted to be sure about what you meant by them, I don't think it's necessary to change the wording.
